# Reason to return updated stack along with top element from pop() method

Tags: python, stack, jax

[This](https://github.com/google/jax/blob/fae98733aa08d407ce678d6034f4a888171fa1c5/jax/_src/lax/stack.py#L63):

```
  def pop(self) -> tuple[Any, Stack]:
    """Pops from the stack, returning an (elem, updated stack) pair."""
```

What is the reason behind returning updated stack along with top element from `pop()` method?

Comment: You can ask this on their thread discussion

Comment: It doesn't return an "updated" Stack *per se*. It's actually a new Stack instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docstring of the `Stack` class: "A bounded functional stack implementation."

A functional implementation generally means that [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) are used.
The `pop` function implements two pure function properties:

- The output does not change when called multiple times with the same input.
- The function does not mutate the stack, ie it does not introduce side effects.

This is why it must return a (mutated) copy of the input `Stack` instead of modifying it.